# Multiple buttons in the child component with the methods in the parent component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a component with two buttons, each with an unique function:

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v - button ref = "button" / >
        <v - button ref = "buttons" / >
    </v-container>
</template>
```

How I want to address both buttons in the parent and apply my two functions, I have written in the parent, on them.

```
<Button @click="refer to the two buttons" />
...
<script>
methodOne(){
    console.log("A")
}
methodTwo() {
    console.log("B")
}
</script>
```

I just don't know how do that correctly. Short: having multiple buttons in the child component and multiple functions in the parent component who should be triggered when the buttons in the child component are triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Vue $emit function inside a child component. So:

Your child component

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <button @click="$emit('aButttonClick')">Button A</button>
        <button @click="$emit('bButttonClick')">Button B</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

your parent component

```js
<ButtonComponent @aButttonClick="methodOne" @bButttonClick="methodTwo" />
...
<script>
methodOne(){
    console.log("A")
}
methodTwo() {
    console.log("B")
}
</script>
```

And you can use emit function inside a function. And you can add additional params to.

See here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html